# Jmeter Recording using company proxy

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I am facing proxy problems (no issue with certificate unidentification found yet) as working on client company proxy. Can you explain what are the things are required to make the proxy with JMeter.

I have the following error:

> "java.net.UnknownHostException: jmeter.apache.org" in jmeter request response and Authentication error 401 in firefox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAF4Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

How are you opening Jmeter? If you are accessing the application using company proxy, you need to launch JMeter throguh proxy as below:
Jmeter -H your proxy -P Port -u username -a password.

Try recoridng the application traffic now!